# div in front of everything with z-index

Tags: css, html, z-index

I have this carousel of products in a page I'm building.

http://flytango.com.ar/test/home-publico.html

When hovering the product, I'd like to show a div with some text.

I'm achieving this by using

```
.item_carrousel_home:hover + .item_carrousel_home_on {
    display: block;
}
```

The div shows up (in green) but I want it to be offset 40px up. So when i try "margin-top:-40px; it gets cut off by the carousel DIV.

I've tried with z-index, but I can't bring the div in front of everything.

```css
.item_carrousel_home:hover + .item_carrousel_home_on {
    display: block;
.item_carrousel_home_on {
    width:220px;
    height:130px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:none;
    position:absolute !important;
    z-index:999999 !important;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:-40px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="carrousel_home">
  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="item_carrousel_home"><img src="imagenes/cellactive.jpg"      alt="Cellactive" width="155" height="200" border="0" />
        <br />Nombre Producto
        <br />en dos lineas</a>
        <div class="item_carrousel_home_on">HOLA</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!--fin del carrousel-->
```

Comment: As repeatedly demanded: Please offer a jsfiddle version of your problem. At http://jsfiddle.net/ you can paste the fragments of code relevant to your problem in three fields: HTML, CSS and JavaScript (or the like). Please paste working code there and add the link to your post for us to help you :)

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AbWYk/

I want the green div to be infront of everithing, and offsetted upwards

Comment: That's a tough one. If you remove the `position: relative` from `<div class="jcarousel-clip">` and it's child `<ul>`, the hover is positioned without being clipped. But obviously the relative positioning of the jcarousel elements are essential to its function.

Comment: Yeap, thats whats driving me nuts

Answer (score 2):

You cannot give a child a higher z-index than it's parent.

Maybe you have to put it in an extra div/span to fit you needs?

**EDIT:**

See http://jsfiddle.net/AbWYk/3/

code:

```
.item_carrousel_home_on {
    width:220px;
    height:130px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:none;
    position:absolute !important;
    z-index:999999 !important;
    margin:-80px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: That really doesn't matter. You can just put it "somewhere", set `display: none` (or hide it behind the rest of the content with a negative z-index). If you want to show your product info (or the like), set `display: block` or increase the z-index.

Comment: sorry men, you'll have to bare with me, im not sure if im following you. Am i not just doing that right now?

Comment: See my edited answer. I put all the margin values into one line. They are processed clockwise (top - left - bottom - right).

Comment: Works on the fiddle but not in the site

Answer (score 0):

```
.item_carrousel_home:hover + .item_carrousel_home_on {
```

Should be:

```
.item_carrousel_home:hover, .item_carrousel_home_on {
```

Comment: Nonetheless you should fill in a closing bracket ( `}` ) after `display: block;` as everything else is overwritten otherwise.. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: btw: If you use the correct CSS syntax and it doesn't show up at all (or not as expected) you should really offer a simplified jsfiddle. Would help the both of us.

Comment: Maybe you can create a jsFiddle to make the problem more clear to us.

Comment: Okay, you might have forgot to paste it in the code example above. I proposed an edit with increased formatting and closing bracket.

Comment: Just replace the code as I said, it will solve the problem. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/AbWYk/1/

Comment: Yes, the green div is the one with a high z-index. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, but i want this to happen only while hovering the product

Comment: Well, we can play this back and forth forever... If you don't offer a more complete version of your fiddle you must accept that we can't help you any further and just try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Im trying to get the whole js code on fiddle but i doesnt work as it's supposed to > http://flytango.com.ar/test/home-publico.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the HOLA div has `position: absolute`, you can use `top:-40` to move it up 40px. I also suggest you add `pointer-events:none;` to stop the flickering.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
    src: url('fonts/helvetica2.eot');
    src: url('fonts/helvetica2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/helvetica2.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/helvetica2.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/helvetica2.svg#helvetica2') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#828282;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-image:url(imagenes/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    text-align:center;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#666666;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#666666;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#666666;
}
/** COLORES **/
 .negro {
    color:#000000;
}
.gris {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
.rojo {
    color:#ED1C2F;
}
/** **/
 #contenedor {
    width:940px;
    height:500px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    width:940px;
    height:147px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(imagenes/shadow_940.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center bottom;
    padding-bottom: 85px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99999;
}
#barra_header {
    width:910px;
    height:23px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-top:0px;
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:normal;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
#idiomas_header {
    float:left;
}
.banderita_header {
    margin-right:7px;
}
#universo_prof_header {
    float:right;
    height: 28px;
    background-image: url(imagenes/flecha_header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:56% 0%;
    margin-top:-5px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
#universo_prof_header a:link {
    font-style:normal;
    color:#828282;
}
.flecha_universo_prof_header {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.logo {
    margin-top:15px;
    float:left;
}
#menu-header {
    width:940px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-3px;
    top:97px;
    z-index:9999 !important;
}
#slider {
    width:940px;
    height:368px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:-45px;
}
#destacados_home {
    font-family:'Helvetica', Arial Narrow;
    font-size:40px;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px #FFFFFF;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style: normal;
    width:940px;
    height:50px;
    color:#808080;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 70px;
    background-image: url(imagenes/linea_destacados.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
#carrousel_home {
    width:940px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.item_carrousel_home {
    width:155px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #4f4f4f;
    line-height: 19px;
}
.item_carrousel_home:hover {
    color:#FF0000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.item_carrousel_home_on {
    width:220px;
    height:130px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:none;
    position:absolute !important;
    z-index:999999 !important;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    top:-40px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.item_carrousel_home:hover + .item_carrousel_home_on {
    display: block;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    background: #FFF;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 920px;
    height:240px;
    padding-left:15px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
    width: 75px;
    height: 245px;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width: 920px;
    height: 275px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-vertical {
    width: 75px;
    height: 245px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: 172px;
    height: 275px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-vertical {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-placeholder {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
/**
 *  Horizontal Buttons
 */
 .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: -50px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url(../imagenes/next-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    left: 5px;
    right: auto;
    background-image: url(../imagenes/prev-horizontal.png);
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:hover, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:focus {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:active {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:hover, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:focus, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    background-position: -96px 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: -48px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url(../imagenes/prev-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
    background-image: url(../imagenes/next-horizontal.png);
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:hover, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:focus {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:active {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:hover, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:focus, .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    background-position: -96px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="carrousel_home">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <li><a href="#" class="item_carrousel_home"><img src="imagenes/cellactive.jpg" alt="Cellactive" width="155" height="200" border="0" /><br />Nombre Producto<br />
en dos lineas</a>

            <div class="item_carrousel_home_on">HOLA</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--fin del carrousel-->
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you need to use:

position: absolute;

in the CSS code to utilize the z-index property.

http://w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp